# Reactjs-How can I navigate with stacknavigator in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I created a trivia app using react-native and the navigation relies heavily on react-navigation.

I want to introduce to the player the option of continuing from where he left. ie: when reopening the application, instead of navigating from A==>B==C==>D, where D is the the actual game screen, How can I achieve the behavior of A===>D, relying on persisted data store ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the last screen visited and use:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate(ScreenName);
```

Just like you do from A to B, you can do directly from A to D. If you have multiple navigator the solution could be different.

Comment: I am splitting the stackNavigator into 6 stackNavigators to override the stack issue of this.props.navigation.goBack() and navigating through all the stack loaded. 
Does this.props.navigation have a history predefined function ?

Comment: No, you should open an issue on react-navigation or see if this past issue can help you: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/983
(even this: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1979)

If it's still an issue on the new react-navigation version you can try to implement your own getStateForAction or override other methods.